# How do I check a string for any number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string similar to this:

```
string = '(1:[0,0,0]; 2:[21,0,12])'
```

Except my string goes on for thousands of numbers.

```
... '4214:[9,93,42])'
```

How do I select the number, colon, and opening bracket? Like this:

```
'1:['
'2:['
'2831:['
'4214:['
```

I want to select each one of these and replace it with a new string: `'('`.

Comment: Where are you getting the string from? There might be a way to convert it directly from the source.

Comment: That string is the source. It's a file that's globally referenced to retrieve data. @Electron

Comment: @Rufflewind's answer is the way I would do it.

Comment: If the string is guaranteed to consist of only numbers inside those lists `[1,2,3]`, you can convert it to a dictionary by replacing the quotes with curly brackets and semicolons with commas. Then you could use something like `exec('variable = ' + formatted_string)`. From then on, you can do all kinds of data manipulation with a dictionary like finding all the values and keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
new_string = re.replace(r'[0-9]+:\[', r'\(', string)
```

This replaces all occurences of `<number>:[` with `(`.

Comment: You have an extra `)`, and probably shouldn't be using `string`.

Comment: It was meant to overwrite `string` but I realize that might cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is already in the form of a dictioanry. Just do the following:

```
In [35]: xx = eval(string.replace(";", ',').replace('(', '{').replace(')', '}'))
```

The result is a dictionary ...

```
In [36]: xx.keys()
Out[36]: [1, 2]

In [37]: xx[2]
Out[37]: [21, 0, 12]
```